# How to access specific value of a nested dictionary when the key is unknown?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have the following nested dictionary:

```
dict1 =  {"relatedUnderlyingInformation": {"SP500":{
                                            "underlying": "SP500",
                                            "ticker": "SPY",
                                            "balls": "S&P Index",
                                            "balls2": "I like meat"}
        }
}
```

If I just want to print the nested dictionary key value for balls2 ("I like meat") without knowing the key, how can I do this? I have tried the following methods and they both don't work:

```
print(
list(dict1.values())[0][0][3]
)
```

and

```
print(
dict1[0][0][3]
)
```

thank you!

Comment: use recursion to iterate through dictionary and  try to match the desired key with the key you want to match

Comment: @sahasrara62 He doesn't know the key. _"without knowing the key, how can I do this?"_

Comment: which key don't you know? if you don't know the "balls2" key, I don't think the question makes sense

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution:

```
>>> dict1 =  {"relatedUnderlyingInformation": {"SP500":{
...                                             "underlying": "SP500",
...                                             "ticker": "SPY",
...                                             "balls": "S&P Index",
...                                             "balls2": "I like meat"}
...         }
... }
>>> def get_last_value(d):
...     if not isinstance(d, dict):
...         return d
...     return get_last_value(list(d.values())[-1])
...
>>> get_last_value(dict1)
'I like meat'
```